# Google OpenID 2.0 phased out - Owin integration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-api, asp.net-identity, owin

Since Google's OpenId 2.0 is phased out, does anyone know what's the best way of getting MVC5 with Asp.Net Identity and Owin working with Google+ for authentication purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's Microsoft's response in a CodePlex issue for the Katana Project...

> Yes, our Google OpenID support has been marked as Obsolete in Katana
>   v3, and our Google OAuth support has been updated to incorporate their
>   breaking changes. See GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions. Expect a
>   v3-beta2 release containing these changes soon, our try our nightly
>   builds.

Source: http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/workitem/274

There is Google+ support in the open source Owin.Security.Providers project ([NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Owin.Security.Providers/) | [GitHub](https://github.com/owin-middleware/OwinOAuthProviders)).